# Flex DataGrid List highlighting

Tags: apache-flex, list, datagrid, adobe, highlight

By default, whenever you rollOver/mouseOver (not sure of the difference) an item in a Datagrid or a List, that item is highlighted with the component's rollOverColor.  I'm just wondering if there's any way to do that programmatically.  I haven't been able to find much help on the issue.  For example, suppose I have two DataGrids.  When I rollOver an item in the first DataGrid, I want to highlight the corresponding index in the second one as well.  Basically, as if two separate cursors were rollOver'ing two separate DataGrids.  How can I do this?

- Ian

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the datagrid's `itemRollOver` event and then select a row in the other datagrid by using it's `selectedIndex` or `selectedItem` properties.

Comment: Completely wrong, how could someone upvote this. This should get -1. Read the question again, he is asking for roll over index not selected index.

Comment: Wow. Settle down. Thing have probably changed a lot in Flex since *a year ago when this was answered*.

Comment: Then try being constructive instead of hostile. You'll get farther.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a custom DataGrid with this function :

```
public function indicesToItemRenderer(rowIndex:int, colIndex:int):IListItemRenderer
    {
        var firstItemIndex:int = verticalScrollPosition - offscreenExtraRowsTop;
        if (rowIndex < firstItemIndex ||
                rowIndex >= firstItemIndex + listItems.length
                )
        {
                return null;
        }

        return listItems[rowIndex - firstItemIndex][colIndex];
    }
```

2) When you want to hightlight an item, call this code :

```
youCustomADG.indicesToItemRenderer(idxRow, idxCol).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER);
```